# North polar stereographic projection is not working

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap, map-projections

I am trying to create a stereographic plot using Basemap offset from the north pole, but the west-east directions are apparently reversed. Is this an error in my implementation, or a bug?

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m = Basemap(projection='stere',
        lat_0=90, lon_0=270,  lat_ts=(90.+35.)/2.,
        llcrnrlon=150,urcrnrlon=-60,llcrnrlat=50,urcrnrlat=50)

m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,360,30),labels=[1,1,1,0])
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,5))
m.drawcoastlines()
m.shadedrelief()
plt.show()
```

Here is the result:
[result from script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4pWa.png)

How might I reproduce the following map (which is offset-centred, and rotated?)

[Restricted map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiJNP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an azimuthal type of map projection always requires a set of proper parameters to get a good result. In this case, Stereographic projection centered at the north pole, its proper parameters are not what you usually use when implement with `PlateCaree` projection which is often used. Here is a working code that you may try.

```
# Stereographic projection coverage
#   should be specified less than half of a hemisphere

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m = Basemap(projection='stere', resolution='c',
        lat_0=90, lon_0=270,  lat_ts=(90.+35.)/2., width=15000000, height=10000000)
# (width, height) is the plot extents in meters

m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0, 360, 30), labels=[1,1,1,0])
m.drawparallels(np.arange(0, 90, 10), labels=[0,0,0,1])
m.drawcoastlines()
m.shadedrelief()
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot (map 1):

[image]

To get other part of the world into the plotting area is achieved by recentering the map.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# projection center point
lon0 = 180
lat0 = 60

m = Basemap(projection='stere', resolution='c',
        lat_0=lat0, lon_0=lon0,  lat_ts=lat0, width=15000000, height=10000000)

m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0, 360, 30), labels=[1,0,0,1])  # left, right, top, bottom
m.drawparallels(np.arange(0, 90, 10), labels=[0,1,1,0])
m.drawcoastlines()
m.shadedrelief()
plt.show()
```

The output plot (map 2):

[image]

By specifying proper values of `llcrnrlon`, `urcrnrlon`, `llcrnrlat`, `urcrnrlat`, in `Basemap()` one can get the map extents as required. Here is another example of plot as requested by the OP.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
m = Basemap(projection='stere', resolution='c',
        lat_0=90, lon_0=-90,  lat_ts=(90.+35.)/2.,
        llcrnrlon=-142, urcrnrlon=78, llcrnrlat=19, urcrnrlat=45)

m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0, 360, 30), labels=[1,0,1,0])  # left, right, top, bottom
m.drawparallels(np.arange(0, 90, 10), labels=[0,1,0,1])
m.drawcoastlines()
m.shadedrelief()
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot (map 3):

[image: map3]

Comment: Thanks - that's really helpful.  If I only wanted the left-hand-side of this map, how would I plot this? The arguments urcrnrlon etc. don't seem to work in this case.

Comment: Thanks @swatchai  - but how might I reproduce a map (which has not only a different centre point, but is also rotated?) Map is attached to the end of my original post.

Comment: @Phil: The best way of saying thanks is clicking the `accept`  button on my answer. :)